# How to save a message in a variable, only to delete it later?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to find a way to save a message as a variable. After it is saved as variable, I will delete the variable. I am making a page-based command for my bot, where each page has a custom reaction that does a custom action. I decided to make a simple navigator for the first page. In the navigator, you react with an emoji and the bot sends a message telling you to choose a page and wait for your message. When the bot receives your message, I want the bot to delete the message it sent.

My code looks like this.

```js
let qsend = message.channel.send("Choose a page to go to.");// sends the bot's message
// bot receives my message!
qsend.delete() // deletes the bot's message
```

When I run it, I get the error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: qsend.delete is not a function`.
I've tried many different solutions, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a message returns a promise. You need to either `await` it or use `Promise#then()`

Using Async/Await

```
// Inside an async function
// .on('message' async message => ... For example
let qsend = await message.channel.send("Choose a page to go to.");

qsend.delete();
```

Using `Promise#then()`

```
message.channel.send("Choose a page to go to.")
   .then(qsend => qsend.delete())
   .catch(console.error);
```

Discord.JS Documentation on [Message#delete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) and [Async/Await](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html)

Answer (score 0):

`message.channel.send()` returns a promise ([see here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)). To delete it shortly after, you should send the message, await the response and delete the returned message after that time.

```js
message.channel.send('Foo bar')
  .then(msg => msg.delete())
  .catch(/* Error handling if the message isn't sent or returned.*/);
```